# How to use 'npm install' without 'sudo'?

Tags: linux, npm, sudo

Unfortunately, I can't just type 'npm install ' and install the package. I must use 'sudo npm install '. Do you know how to make npm work without running it as administrator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm throws error without sudo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)

Comment: I typed:
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
and it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 7):

**Uninstall any existing instances:**

```
sudo npm uninstall npm -g
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/{npm*,node*,man1/node*}
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules
```

**Install any missing required libraries:**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++ flex bison gperf ruby perl libsqlite3-dev libfontconfig1-dev libicu-dev libfreetype6 libssl-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev python libx11-dev libxext-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

**Download and install nvm:**

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh | bash
```

**Ensure permanent access from every bash instance:**

```
sudo gedit ~/.bash_profile
```

**when the file opens in the editor, type the following, save and exit gedit:**

```
export NVM_DIR="/home/your_username/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

**next, run:**

```
nvm ls-remote
```

**and choose a version you like from the list (I prefer current LTS). Then install it like this:**

```
nvm install 6.11.0
```

**check if everything is ok:**

```
npm -v
```

**now you should be able to run npm without sudo**

Comment: "now you should be able to run npm without sudo"
no i'm not.